# Android: In Eclipse project missing Google APIs?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a work space with many projects. One of them is suddenly missing the Google APIs libraries even though it is clearly checked. the properties file lists it correctly.

How do I get Eclipse to add these to this one project?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once i had problem like this : i tried many but can't find and positive solution.
(1)
  - make new project with required target and move src, res, ref and manifest to this new project.
(2)
- Just try remove auto build option from project menu and then delete gen folder and just build project and then clean & build project.

Answer (score 0):

This often works for me:

- Select another build target and click 'Apply'. When the update is finished I select the previous build target and then 'Apply' again.
- Remove 'bin' and 'gen' directories from my project and select the clean option in the project menu.